# How can I use onblur() option with jeditable plugin?

Tags: jquery, onblur

I am working in MVC  & using jeditable grid plugin.

I want to know how can i use the onblur() option to manage submit?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it....

```
$('#element_ud').editable('path/to/edit', {
  indicator : 'Saving...',
  loadurl : '/load/url',
  type   : 'select',
  submit : 'OK',
  onblur : 'submit',
  tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
});
```